# Where should the audio-input be available in this RF circuit?

Tags: capacitor, amplifier, circuit-design, rf, audio

Let me show you what I have tried so far. First of all, the circuit below has been tested and this one works for sure. The audio signal can be heard on an FM radio at 100MHz.

[image: circuit is working]

The second below is working, too. I have seen that the carrier signal is being caught on an FM radio. The silence is just a statement for that. The first circuit above let me inject audio signal without problems. The second one instead lets me be off business. Nothing is working. I have no audio signal. With one exception, that when I amplify my audio source very loud, I can hear some weak fragments from that source.

[image: circuit that is not working]

Can you tell me if there is something I missed? You can see in the second circuit that I tried to amplify the carrier signal. Tell me if that is a deal how things work with carrier signal properly.

Comment: Your biasing is all messed up for the second case--don't forget that you now have *three* base-emitter junctions that need to be foward-biased into operation. You will need to tweak resistor values, and maybe capacitively couple your input into it instead of resistively coupling it.

Comment: @Hearth Can you give me a link or a clue for example, how to do that by a pic? I would accept that for an answer with an upvote. :)

Comment: I don't have the energy to put any more specifics to it or do any calculations on it right now, else I would have made that an answer.

Comment: @Hearth ok, anytime.

Comment: I understand that,  not the carrier signal is the problem, but the audio signal must be amplified properly according to many settings, which should be integrated into the second circuit. I know a couple tricks how to do that. The main issue here is, how to do that with an example for this second circuit.

Comment: What is your reason for adding Q2 and Q3 to the circuit?  What are they supposed to do?

Comment: In the first schematic, C1 is connected directly across the battery.  68 pF seems like a very small and specific value for a bypass capacitor.

Comment: perhaps before saying what is working or not, you could start by saying what you are hoping to achieve.

Comment: Please do your homework and research "capacitively coupling" that Hearth suggest.

Comment: Q2 and Q3 are not polarized, they act like two diodes (the b-e junctions) on the emitter of Q1, allowing only the positive peaks of the audio signal to pass. The capacitance resulting from the series of C1, C2 and C3 is approximately 22pF, which does not disturb the oscillator.